# How common is it for universities to create new positions for dual hires?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, career, advice

Let's say you happen to be a mathematician, and your spouse is also an academic and in a humanities field in which there are very few jobs advertised.  Assuming that you can convince universities to hire you on a tenure-track level, what are the chances that they will be able (or willing) to create a position for your spouse?  If you already have a job that you are reasonably happy with, is it at all reasonable to apply to positions where there is nothing advertised for your spouse in the area in hopes that you can arrange something for them if you get a job offer?

I'm mostly interested in the US and research I-esque jobs, though I would be happy to hear about the situation in other countries.

**EDIT:** Since [Yemon asks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38784/how-common-is-it-for-universities-to-create-new-positions-for-dual-hires#comment90876_38784), here are some examples of answers I would like to see:

- specific anecdotes about this happening or failing to happen.  I don't want to violate anyone's privacy, but presumably some of these can be anonymized or are a matter of public record.
- comments from people who've been in administrative capacities in departments/on hiring committees about whether this is something they would even attempt to arrange, and whether they've had any success with it in the past.
- obviously, actual data on how often this happens would be great, but I have trouble imagining it exists, at least specifically for mathematics.

I'm failing to see why Andrew thinks that no one will be able to surmise anything from a long list of anecdotes.  Obviously, it would be better to have data, but when trying to figure out what one could even hope to ask from a hiring committee, knowing what has happened in the past is very valuable information.

Comment: This question has little or nothing to do with mathematics *per se*.  I think you might get a more definitive response by asking it on one of the fora at the Chronicle of Higher Education.  

Comment: Are you asking for anecdotes, *data*, or survey results?

Comment: This isn't a question that is about research mathematics, nor is it one that I expect people here to be able to give a _definitive_ answer to.  As phrased, I expect a list of anecdotes from which it will be impossible to draw a conclusion.

Comment: I would say it's certainly a question of interest to research mathematicians (both those who want to get jobs, and those who want to make hires). I would also argue that it's worth asking in a mathematics specific forum, since the ability to push these things through administration may vary quite a bit from department to department.  The point about Chronicle of Higher Ed fora is a good one, and I may try there as well.  I'll address what sort of answers would be good in an edit.

Comment: I think some parts or aspects of this question might admit an informed answer which the questioner doesn't have access to - I'm thinking of responses by people like Deane Yang, for instance, to questions of protocol or procedure. So I'm not voting to close. However, since I'm not sure right now whether I think the question is right for MO, I'm not "voting against closing" at the moment.

Comment: @anonymous: sure, the administration's attitude towards dual hires does vary from department to department, but it varies just as much or more from university to university.  If your question is about the math department at a *specific* university, it might be a good strategy to identify the university so that someone from that place can contact you (presumably privately) and share specialized information.  

Comment: meta discussion <http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/671/howcommonisitforuniversitiestocreatenewpositionsfo/>

Comment: It might help if you could say more about why you are asking this question (presumably you will have no trouble maintaining the spirit of your MO name). Specifically, I wonder if your spouse either has no academic job or is in an unpleasant one rather than, say, is about to graduate from a good school with a strong thesis.  Also, are there few jobs advertised only for temporary reasons (e.g., the economy) or is it always that way (e.g., Tuvan studies)? Unless the spouse's work can stand on its own merits, the result is unlikely to be satisfactory if the spouse is seeking a tenure-track job. 



Comment: I suggest only applying to places where the spouse can find ads or where the spouse's work is already represented by current faculty (and write to ask if they are hiring this year). 
To turn things around, my dept. was once asked by admins to hire someone so a humanities hire could be made. The math prof. had many years of grant support and was close to retirement, so it wouldn't have been a long-term commitment for us. We were told the mathematician was willing to do what was needed for the spouse to be hired and a joint offer was made. (The couple did not come.) You sound younger than that.

Comment: I have heard that some humanities departments can be more specific in their job ads than mathematics (typical for us may be "differential geometry", while they may say "such-and-such literature of the 19th century"), which would make it even more important to focus on places which have ads for the spouse than ads for you.

Comment: I doubt anecdotal data is very useful. I've heard many stories of spouses languishing in non-TT positions, sometimes until they moved somewhere else. It appears that some places will shamelessly take advantage of the situation, and the current economy can only make it more likely. But this is only anecdotal (and mostly 3rd hand).

Comment: One case went something like this.  A humanities department wanted to hire a certain woman.  They contacted the math dept and ask if we would like to hire her husband.  The husband was a top-rate mathematician, so of course we say yes.  The humanities department even provided some money for part of the salary.  We make an offer to the husband.  (Perhaps causing some resentment within our department because of how high the salary was.)  But in the end they did not come, they stayed put.  Now we can wonder: was the whole thing a ploy by the wife to gain concessions at her existing institution?

Comment: @Gerald: this is swiftly wandering off-topic, but: the word "ploy" makes it sound like you think the couple did something unethical.  From what you have said, that's not clear: as long as they seriously considered your department's offer, I think what they did is fine.  Among colleagues that I've spoken to about this, it is essentially unanimously agreed that nowadays, the only way to maintain something like your "market rate" salary at a job you have held for several years is to acquire outside job offers.  

Comment: Seconding Pete L. Clark, "playing the outside offer game" is dangerous (if your home institution does not make a competitive counter-offer, then it's a bit of a "screw you", and so you shouldn't play unless you are willing to leave for the new school) but can also be essential: many schools will hire at the market rate but do not give "market rate" raises.  This is true across the academy, and not specific to math (my knowledge of this type of thing happens to come from talking to professors in non-math departments).

Comment: I hope to hear some positive anecdotes as well, but maybe a better place to seek this sort of information is on the Chronicle for Higher Ed's forums.  They have a section on the 2-body problem there.  Any information on a 2-body problem, with one body in the sciences division and one body in the humanities division should be relevant.

Comment: I think that it is not uncommon, if one department is very interested in a candidate whose spouse is also an academic, to ask the relevant department if they are interested in hiring the spouse.  If the candidate is sufficiently attractive, there may even be offers made
to the other department to sweeten things
(part of the salary coming from a different pot, or the position not counting towards that departments overall quota of positions).  However, I think it is fairly unusual to *force* the other department to accept the spouse as a hire; in other words, the spouse probably has to stand ...

Comment: ... to *some* extent on their own merits (since if a department is not at all interested in a person, it is unlikely that they will want that person in their department, sweeteners or not).  These remarks apply more to permanent jobs; I think that is easier to perhaps get the spouse a temporary job (adjunct, visiting position, ...), especially if the other department is large or has subsantial service teaching requirements (e.g. language departments).   But such arrangements are obviously not very satisfactory in the long run, and I have known couples to move through several different ...

Comment: ... universities until finally finding one where they both have stable employment.   

Comment: @Emerton: I just thought I'd remark that my spouse is definitely sufficiently attractive.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question that lingers on the unanswered queue. Nowadays, it would be migrated to Academia.SE, but that site didn't exist when this was asked. Anyway, I'll try to answer, in case it helps future MO visitors.

First, yes, this kind of thing *does* happen. It's known as a "spousal hire." I've seen it happen many times during my career. For example, as an undergraduate at a small liberal arts college, two of my professors in the math department were married and were already married before they got hired. As a PhD student, there was another couple in the exact same situation (both in the math department). I'm now a professor at a liberal arts college, that has around 200 tenure-track faculty. I know of three cases of a married couple that was already married before they got hired. I know of other cases where one was hired and then years later was able to get their spouse hired. I also know of many cases where one is hired tenure track, and the spouse is hired on a long-term, renewable, but non-tenure track line. The difference often depends on the research productivity of the spouse (if they have a PhD but don't do research, they get the latter type of appointment).

I've been on hiring committees where we've been open to trying to arrange this, though in the examples I can think of, the candidate/couple didn't take the job offer(s). Indeed, we have language about spousal hires in [our faculty handbook, which is publicly available](https://catalog.denison.edu/faculty-handbook/).

> Spousal/Partner Faculty Appointments

> As part of its program to attract and retain faculty, Denison attempts to offer continuing non-tenure-track appointments to qualified spouses/partners of faculty. Such appointments are initially contingent upon institutional need and the qualifications of the spouse/partner; reappointment is contingent upon continuing need as well as satisfactory performance as determined through the regular review process. These will normally be part-time appointments. Spouses/partners in such appointments are eligible to apply for full-time positions, including tenure-track positions, when they occur.

Bigger universities can often solve two body problems more easily than smaller ones, because they have more overall demand, bigger departments, a wider variety of departments, etc. Most liberal arts colleges don't have a statement in the faculty handbook like the one above. At a liberal arts college, the issue is that, if the spouse's natural department doesn't have need for additional professors (based on student demand), then it would be harder to create a tenure line in that department, but it's still possible if the spouse is a strong candidate in their own right. Often, it's easier for us to arrange a spousal hire when the spouse is also a mathematician; for one thing because our department always has plenty of student demand, and for another thing, we're unlikely to object to a new tenure line. But if they're trying to get hired in some other department D, you could imagine a situation where the spouse's research interests run counter to the prevailing theme of department D, and they would prefer the spouse on a non-tenure line.

Lastly, there's the question of when is the optimal moment to ask for a spousal hire. Generally speaking, the answer is "right after you get your job offer." That's your negotiating window. If the spousal hire is most important for your overall happiness and success, this is where you need to ask for it, argue for it, and fight for it. That might mean you get less start-up funds, etc. But, if you accept your offer without mentioning the spouse, and then hope they can get a job later on, things will be worse. For one thing, there will be less pressure to give you what you want. The spouse might be offered work as an adjunct, but once they've shown a willingness to work for the university under those conditions, it's unlikely that a tenure track offer would materialize. Department D may try to keep the spouse as a long-term visitor, and use their next tenure track hire to get someone else, thereby growing. From what I've seen, to put the pressure back on the university to truly solve the "two body problem," both you and your spouse might need to go back on the job market and get a competing offer. This is why it's best to get the spousal hire right away, before you've moved and put down roots. This advice is echoed in many threads over on academia.SE, that I link to below (in no particular order):

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/164166/when-is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-spousal-hire

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/186289/what-is-the-long-term-professional-status-of-a-spousal-hire

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/127114/spousal-hire-for-girlfriend-in-us-university

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56936/how-to-approach-the-dean-and-or-provost-about-a-years-old-two-body-problem

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32369/when-during-the-application-process-should-a-candidate-mention-that-their-spouse

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/164166/when-is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-spousal-hire

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/157752/two-body-problem-in-academia-in-the-us

Comment: It should be mentioned that the situation described in this answer is specific to North American universities. I cannot speak for all of Europe, but at least in the Netherlands (and I'm pretty sure the same goes for Germany), this is almost unthinkable. Not because the will isn't there, but because universities are state-funded and have a lot more transparency/accountability rules for new hires. For a new position, there usually has to be a new call. (That said, the problem is a little less urgent because the density of research universities is probably higher than in most of the US.)

Comment: Yes, definitely. I have no idea how it works if at all in Europe.